# Clear cache for specific S3 bucket items/files manually/using S3 Console GUI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I updated some images manually, but changes aren't reflected on my website due to caching.

What are some approaches to *manually* updating the cache using the GUI? (Say you don't want to go to the time/trouble of installing AWS CLI / Boto3 just now).

Answer (score -1):

Here's the one method I found. I'm interested to learn others!

1. Browse to your file `https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/BUCKETNAME/PATH/TO/FILE/`
2. Check/select items for which to clear cache
3. Select the `Edit Metadata` action (under Actions menu, "Edit actions" group)
4. Note the warning text reads: `This action creates a new version of the object with updated settings and a new last-modified date.` (This is the desired effect.) Note the other items, as they may have an impact in your case.
5. Press "Save Changes" (not necessary to make any other changes on this screen).
6. Caches will be cleared for selected items immediately.

Pros:

- Handpick files
- Cache updates immediately

Cons:

- Time-consuming if files are in multiple directories (multiple files at same path can be checked at once)
- There may be undesired side effects, depending on bucket ownership/policy, per the Edit Metadata screen's warning

[AWS S3 Console: Item actions: Edit Metadata: Edit Metadata info text states that cache will be updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoeeU.png)

Comment: How will this work? The decision to cache an image was made by an external system based upon the Cache-Control/Expires headers present when the object was previously fetched by that external system.